# Trigger in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have class table which references student table.
I write a trigger to +1 amount of exellent_eng when insert >=8 score of English subject but it has error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tr_addExellentEnglishStudent, Line 3 [Batch Start Line 1]
>   The multi-part identifier "x.exellent_Eng" could not be bound.

I'm using SSMS.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_addExellentEnglishStudent ON dbo.dbo_student AFTER INSERT AS 
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.dbo_class
    SET x.exellent_Eng += 1
    FROM dbo.dbo_class x
    JOIN dbo.dbo_student s ON s.class_id = x.class_id
    JOIN dbo.dbo_score c ON c.student_id = s.student_id
    WHERE (c.subject_id = 1 AND c.score_id >= 8)
END
```

Comment: It would be `UPDATE x`, not `UPDATE dbo.dbo_class`, but why is your trigger not referencing the `inserted` object?

Comment: @Larnu With SQL Server, it can also be `UPDATE dbo.dbo_class`.

Comment: Either use `UPDATE x SET x.exellent_Eng ...` or remove the `x.`.

Comment: I removed x but my trigger not working, please help me. I'm new on trigger

Comment: True, @GSerg, but `UPDATE x` is far more clear. `UPDATE dbo.dbo_Class` with a `FROM dbo.dbo_class x` *could* infer 2 instances of the object `dbo.dbo_Class`; especially as one is aliased and the other not.

Comment: Is this trigger even on the correct table? Should it not be on the `dbo_score` table? I assume the `dbo_student` record must be created before any `dbo_score` record for the student in question… Right?

Comment: yes, it must trigger to dbo_score

Answer (score 0):

Few points to correct here:

1. I don't think you want your trigger on the `dbo_student` table, because when you first insert a student they won't have any scores. I think you wanted the trigger on adding a new `dbo_score` record?
2. As noted in the comments if you alias the table you are updating you should use the notation `update <alias>` e.g. `update x`
3. You don't prefix the column(s) to update with the table name/alias, SQL Server knows which table you are updating.
4. You probably want to restrict the update to students affected by using the `Inserted` pseudo-table.

```sql
    CREATE TRIGGER tr_addExellentEnglishStudent ON dbo.dbo_score
    AFTER INSERT AS 
    BEGIN
      UPDATE x SET
        exellent_Eng += 1
      FROM dbo.dbo_class x
      JOIN dbo.dbo_student s ON s.class_id = x.class_id
      JOIN dbo.dbo_score c ON c.student_id = s.student_id
      WHERE (c.subject_id = 1 AND c.score_id >= 8)
      and c.id in (select id from Inserted)
    END
```

Note: this doesn't consider any of the edge cases which might arise e.g. if you update an existing score from 7 to 8 then technically you would want to increase your `excellent_Eng` result. Similarly if you delete a score or update it from 8 to 7 you would want to decrease it. For these reasons if can be simpler to re-calculate the absolute result rather than making incremental changes.